# How to debug Entity Framework Proxies?

Tags: entity-framework, poco

After a couple weeks experimenting with Entity Framework 5.0 I think I understand the basics.  There's two types of proxies - lazy loading only and change tracking.  I know how to enable/disable each and when to use them.  However, I want to SEE these classes.  I want to be able to step into them at debug time and I want to see what the logic actually does.  However, since they are runtime-generated, Visual Studio can't debug them.  Ideally I'd be able to pre-compile them, but right now I just want to see what they're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can actually debug proxies - at least not using Visual Studio. The types are generated on the fly. The code that generates proxies is here: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/190eef267fc7#src%2fEntityFramework%2fCore%2fObjects%2fInternal%2fEntityProxyFactory.cs (note that this is how it is done in EF6 but it has not changed much since EF5). You may also want to take a look at this blog post: http://davedewinter.com/2010/04/08/viewing-generated-proxy-code-in-the-entity-framework/ - with some hacking you will be able to save generated types to disk and use reflector to see the code.

Comment: Yes they are in EF5 and EF6 and I don't think there are any plans of removing them - you can always disable then. Without proxies lazy loading would not work.